# How do I initialize a pointer to pointer in golang?

Tags: go

How do I initialize a struct with a double pointer field?
I am trying to initialize a struct as below:

```
type atype struct {
  val string
}

a := &struct {
    StringValue string
    Pointer **atype
}{
    StringValue: "FOO",
//this is the relevant bit
    Pointer : &(&atype{ 
      val: "test"
    })
}
```

This gives me an error : `invalid pointer type **basicAppConfig for composite literal`

What is wrong in my logic? I take the pointer to a pointer to the value.

I also tried to use

```
reflect.PtrTo(&atype{
    val: "string"
})
```

without success...

Comment: If you're ok with initializing only to first pointer, having the pointed-to pointer be nil, you can use `new` to your heart's content. https://play.golang.org/p/995hzR3EVWQ

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Pointers are not addressable unless assigned to a variable.  The ability to take the address of a composite literal without assigning it to a variable is limited to structs, arrays, slices, and maps.

To do what you want to do, you have to assign the pointer to a variable first, after which you can assign the address of that (pointer) variable within the struct literal:

https://play.golang.org/p/7WyS732H3cZ

```
package main

type atype struct {
    val string
}

func main() {
    at := &atype{
        val: "test",
    }

    a := &struct {
        StringValue string
        Pointer     **atype
    }{
        StringValue: "FOO",
        Pointer:     &at,
    }

    _ = a
}
```

References:

- https://golang.org/ref/spec#Address_operators
- https://golang.org/ref/spec#Composite_literals